# Visitor shows too much output

Tags: python, antlr, antlr4

Im trying ANTLR4 in Python to parse C++ code, I want to find where a variable/object etc.. is get initialized and where that variable/object is assigned to another variable/object.

I started by implementing `visitAssignmentexpression` and `visitInitdeclarator` on the code below.

```
    int i;
    int b, c;
    int d;
    i = 10;
    b = i;
    c = b;
    d += c;
    std::string str = "TEST";
    ping(argv[1]);
    Person *p = new Person();
    Person p2 = new Person();
    p->get_numbers();
    p2.get_numbers();
```

For `visitInitdeclarator` I got the following output which is very confusing for me, for example why I get `str="TEST"` but not `b = i` or `i = 10`.

```
i
b
c
d
str="TEST"
p2=newPerson()
```

and for `visitAssignmentexpression` I got the following output, I was expecting LValue or RValue etc... but there i got even some function calls as well!

```
i=10
10
b=i
i
c=b
b
d+=c
c
"TEST"
ping(argv[1])
argv[1]
1
Person*p=newPerson()
newPerson()
newPerson()
p->get_numbers()
p2.get_numbers()
```

I should not be hard that Im new to ANTLR and some of this outputs are a bit confusing.
This is basically how my code look like,

```
from antlr4 import *
from antlr4.tree.Tree import TerminalNodeImpl
from CPP14Lexer import *
from CPP14Parser import *
from CPP14Visitor import *




class TREEVisitor(CPP14Visitor):
    def visitFunctionCallPostfixexpression(self, ctx:CPP14Parser.FunctionCallPostfixexpressionContext):
        #print("{}\t{}".format(ctx.getText(), ctx.getChildCount()))
        return self.visitChildren(ctx)


    def visitAssignmentexpression(self, ctx:CPP14Parser.AssignmentexpressionContext):
        print(ctx.getText())
        return self.visitChildren(ctx)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_stream = FileStream(sys.argv[1])
    cpplex = CPP14Lexer(input_stream)
    commtokstream = CommonTokenStream(cpplex)
    cpparser = CPP14Parser(commtokstream)
    print("parse errors: {}".format(cpparser._syntaxErrors))

    tree = cpparser.translationunit()

    tv = TREEVisitor()
    tv.visit(tree)


    visitor = CPP14Visitor()
    visitor.visit(tree)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the grammar file with [Alternative Labels](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#alternative-labels), now it look like this and it seems to give me the result that i want,

```
assignmentexpression
   : conditionalexpression                                     #otherassignments
   | logicalorexpression assignmentoperator initializerclause  #theassignments
   | throwexpression                                           #otherassignments
   ;
```